# Integer Addition and Multiplication are Well Defined

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am supposed to show that addition and multiplication are well defined in $\mathbb{Z}_n$. I don't have much experience will the term well defined nor experience doing proofs with it. I would appreciate hints related to how to properly prove this property.

Comment: What does it mean for an operation (or for a map in general) to be well-defined?

Comment: My textbook defines it as "the operation under consideration is well defined if the result is independent of the representatives chosen in the equivalence classes"

Comment: Yes. Do you understand that definition? What are the equivalence classes of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure

Comment: Yeah, they through "well defined" and assume it's clear.  "Well defined" means, well, unambiguous.    Given the definition, with any input there will be only one unique interpretation.  Example p=m/n $\in$ Q, then f(p) = m + n is not well defined because 1/2 = 2/4 so f(.5) could equal either 3 or 6.

Comment: so what you need to do is to show that for any a and b that a+b can only have one possible interpretation.

Comment: You *must* understand what the equivalence classes are in this situation. If you don’t, go back and master the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a' = a \mod n$ means $ a' \in \{a_i| a_i= a + jn|$ for any $j \in Z\}$.

So you simply need to show that this is well-defined. i.e.  That for  for *any* $a', a~, b', b~$ where $a' = a~ \mod n$ and $b' = b~ \mod n$ then $a' + b' = a~ + b~ \mod n$ and there is no ambiguity

Answer (score 1):

Landau's
"Foundations of Analysis"
devotes a fair amount of
time to this.
If you read the "Preface
for the Teacher",
he talks about how 
properly defining
x+y (and x y)
had to be done carefully.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in this context it makes sense to think of addition and multiplication as binary operations; i.e. $+: \mathbb{Z}_{n} \times \mathbb{Z}_{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ given by $(x,y) \mapsto x + y \mod n$ and $\cdot: \mathbb{Z}_{n} \times \mathbb{Z}_{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ given by $(x,y) \mapsto x \cdot y \mod n$. In order to show that $+$ and $\cdot$ are well-defined, let $a \equiv b \mod n$ and $c \equiv d \mod n$ and then deduce that $a + c \equiv b + d \mod n$ and $a \cdot c \equiv b \cdot d \mod n$.

Answer (score 0):

Addition is trivial. Consider multiplication. Let $a \equiv a' \mod m$ and $b \equiv b' \mod m$. Then notice that
$$
ab - a'b' = ab-a'b + a'b - a'b' = (a-a')b + a'(b-b').
$$
The last two terms are obviously divisible by $m$. Hence, $ab \equiv a'b' \mod m$.